# Error using image in php strings

Tags: php

Hello i am newbie in php 
I am having a simple php error 
I did google. but wasnt able to figure out the exact keywords

```
 <?php
 $vtext="<img alt="" src="/wp-content/themes/9GAG/images/smileynearvote.JPG" style="width: 15px; height: 17px; " />";
 ?>
```

This is how i call it

```
 <?php echo $vtext ?>
```

But when i use this i get an Internal server Error

i did google only founded that how to create an image with  php

but didnt find how to use it string

My cms is wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your `"` (double quotes) or enclose the entire string in `'` single quotes:

```
 $vtext = '<img alt="" src="/wp-content/themes/9GAG/images/smileynearvote.JPG" style="width: 15px; height: 17px; " />';
```

I encourage you to read more about [Strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

**Note:** This may not be the only error. When asking about errors you should always post the full error message and the offending line and the line above it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `"` in your string

```
$vtext="<img alt=\"\" src=\"/wp-content/themes/9GAG/images/smileynearvote.JPG\" style=\"width: 15px; height: 17px; \" />";
```

Read more http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double